# Count number of row in a joint table using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with the query below. I am trying to count the number of Schedule message and Send Message but the query output don't reflect the data in the database

SQL Query

```
SELECT Max(dbo.team.teamname)         AS teamname,
   Max(team.id)                   AS teamid,
   Max(teamlookup.id)             AS TeamLockupId,
   (SELECT Count(team.id)
    FROM   textmessage
    WHERE  dontsendbefore IS NOT NULL
           AND team.id = team.id) AS CountSchedulemessage,
   (SELECT Count(team.id)
    FROM   textmessage
    WHERE  messagesent != 1
           AND team.id = team.id) AS CountSendMessage
 FROM   dbo.textmessage
   INNER JOIN dbo.teamlookup
           ON dbo.textmessage.teamlookupid = dbo.teamlookup.id
   INNER JOIN dbo.team
           ON dbo.teamlookup.teamid = dbo.team.id
GROUP  BY team.id
```

What I am getting when I run the query

[image]

What I am looking to achieve

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: team.id = team.id...

Comment: Consider using Aliases too; it'll make your code much more succinct (and easier to read). :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the correlation of the subqueries is wrong:

```
 (SELECT Count(team.id)
    FROM   textmessage
    WHERE  dontsendbefore IS NOT NULL
           AND team.id = team.id) AS CountSchedulemessage,
```

The predicate of the `WHERE` clause simply compares `team.id` to itself. You should compare to `id` of `textmessage` instead:

```
 (SELECT Count(team.id)
    FROM   textmessage
    WHERE  dontsendbefore IS NOT NULL
           AND textmessage.team_id = team.id) AS CountSchedulemessage,
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Max(dbo.team.teamname)         AS teamname,
   Max(team.id)                   AS teamid,
   Max(teamlookup.id)             AS TeamLockupId,
   (SELECT Count(team.id)
    FROM   textmessage t2
    WHERE  dontsendbefore IS NOT NULL
           AND t2.team.id = t.team.id) AS CountSchedulemessage,
   (SELECT Count(team.id)
    FROM   textmessage t3
    WHERE  messagesent != 1
       AND t3.team.id = t.team.id) AS CountSendMessage
 FROM   dbo.textmessage t
   INNER JOIN dbo.teamlookup
           ON dbo.textmessage.teamlookupid = dbo.teamlookup.id
   INNER JOIN dbo.team
           ON dbo.teamlookup.teamid = dbo.team.id
GROUP  BY team.id
```

Comment: Use aliases, here I did t2 and t3, otherwise team.id = team.id does not make sense.